# How to query mongodb from jasper

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports

How to query mongodb from jasper where the authentication db seats separate from the query database. I'm able to connect the mongodb by providing the connection string having the authentication db name like something

mongodb://etlwfm:w0rk_3tlQA@*.*.*.*,*1.*1.*1.*1,*2.*2.*2.*2/admin?replicaSet=rs0

I could verify the connection was successful. But while providing the query it never return any results. The DB which I wants to fetch data from is wfm_dev. But looks the query assumes the data resides in admin db only. Is there any way I can mention the database name from which I would like to fetch the data from.

Comment: Any such tool will use a standard library for the connection which will work out "where to authenticate" for you. All **you** need to do is provide the correct database name to connect to where you actually want to run your reporting from. Therefore provide `wfm_dev` instead of `admin` in the URL. If you still cannot see the collections, then you don't have appropriate permissions, and need to get that sorted out.

Comment: Is there anyway we can refer the database name while querying. The way we do in RDMS like DB-Name.Table-Name. If that is not possible then we may need to add the authentication level to the particular database name instead of maintaining that on separate db like admin.